# Accessing my documents directly on windows 7 shows weird stuff, what can I do?

Tags: windows-7

'My windows 7 "my documents" folder is now full of files only (and no folders) - how can i solve this problem?'

I am using windows 7 and something weird happened.  when I access "my documents" directly, I see a stream of a TON of files - as if all of the files in my folders were removed and put into a single directory.  There are no folders seen when I access my documents this way.

HOWEVER, when i access "my documents" via "my computer" --> "c:\users\myuid\my documents", then I see everything in its neat and tidy with the files that I expect to be in folders in the folders.

I did run anti-virus and spybot / adaware and it reported no issues that would affect this.

Can someone tell me how I can get the quick access to "my documents" to load properly???

Thanks

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of what you're seeing? It would help us work out what might be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed the "**Arrange by**" property of your library. Open My Documents in the usual way. At the top right corner of the window there is a combo box titled "Arrange by". Use the "**Folder**" value there.

Comment: Thank you!  Never knew about that one, saved me a massive headache!

Comment: I'm glad I did!